# Need to submit Sitemap for my blog

Tags: google-search-console

I write my blog posts and after that generate sitemap.xml. Now I want to know that when I update any info in that at that time sitemap automatically fetched only new updates or overwrite old updates ya we resubmit sitemap.xml in webmaster..?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to overwrite old updates or resubmit sitemap.xml in webmaster.